# PHP json_encode to JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

PHP json_encode as AJAX var "result":

```
[{"id":"139","assettypeid":"3","name":"skin1","body":"skin1.jpg"}]
```

I'm trying to access each property, but I can't:

```
for (var i =0;i < result.length-1;i++)
{
  var item = result[i];
  console.log (item.id + item.name + item.body);
}
```

All I see is:

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
...
```

And there are way too many iterations ... as you can see in the JSON above, there should only be 4 loops.

Comment: What does `console.log(result);` show? And please add the code where you retrieve and parse the json encoded data!

Comment: [{"id":"139","assettypeid":"3","name":"skin1","body":"skin1.jpg"}]

Comment: Why do you subtract from the length? `i < result.length - 1` should be `for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use JSON.parse

```
var items = JSON.parse(result)
```

http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

I modified my answer to create a JSON call to a server side file like PHP or Ruby. If you are using jQuery try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url-of-your-server-side.com/server-side-file-name.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            console.log (item.id + item.name + item.body);
        });
    error: function(){
        // execute upon failure
    }
```

Data is the variable that holds your array provided by your ajax request.

Comment: The reason for this is because you didn't parse your JSON before passsing it through the loop. In your example above, you did not add the part of your script that retrieve the JSON data and parses it. I modified my answer to add the jQuery version to parse and loop your server-side data.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var item in result){
    console.log(item.id, item.name, item.body);
}
```

Comment: you should not use such `for in` construction without checking if the `result` is an object or a prototype property