# Why is return not working in getJSON and why cant I write into variable from getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which uses `getJSON` but its not working like I expected.

```
function balbla(name, param) {
        $.getJSON("/blabla.json?name=" + name + "&param=" + param, function(data) {
                return data.bla;
        });
}
```

When I use `alert(data.bla)` in the getJSON method it works but when I try `return data.bla` it doesnt. Also when I create a variable and try to write the value of `data.bla` to it it simply doesnt work!

// I tried this:

```
function getRouteData(name, param) {
    return $.getJSON('/routes_js.json', {route:name, opt: param});
}
function getRoute(name, param) {
        getRouteData(name, param).done(function(data) {
                return data.route;
        });
}
```

But when I call `getRoute("bla", "blub")` it still returns `undefined`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341365/php-json-encode-to-js/10341552#10341552

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery getJSON - Return value to the caller function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229307/jquery-getjson-return-value-to-the-caller-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous. You cannot easily return a value in such a function that depends on the result of the AJAX call. Change your function to accept a callback:

```
function balbla(name, param, cb) {
    $.getJSON('/blabla.json', {name:name, param: param}, function(data) {
        cb(data.bla);
    });
}
```

And use it like this:

```
balbla('foo', 'bar', function(bla) {
    // do stuff
});
```

An even cleaner way would be returning the jqXHR object:

```
function balbla(name, param) {
    return $.getJSON('/blabla.json', {name:name, param: param});
}
```

When calling it, use the *deferred/promise* interface of the jqXHR object to attach a success callback:

```
balbla('foo', 'bar').done(function(data) {
    alert(data.bla);
});
```

Note that using `$.ajax()` in synchronous mode is not an option you should consider at all. It may hang the browser's UI (or at least the active tab) until the request finished. Besides that, asynchronous callbacks are the way everyone does it.

If you do not like using callback functions, you could use a preprocessor such as [tamejs](http://tamejs.org) to generate the asynchronous functions automatically.

Comment: you could simplify this a lot just by returning `$.getJSON` and having the calling code use the promise to attach callback. You also get error callbacks for free that way.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried the secound cleaner way but it still doesnt work for me!

Comment: Are you using an old jQuery version? Do you get an error? How does your real code look like? What you posted smells like a example you never tried to run (for example, the function name looks typo'd)

Comment: I tried it using callbacks now it works. Im using the newest jquery function. The function is like I tried to run it.

Answer (score 3):

The function with your return statement:

```
function(data) {
    return data.bla;
}
```

… is not being called by your code (it is being called deep inside jQuery), so you have no way to put an assignment of the left hand side of the function call.

It is also being called as part of an asynchronous function, so the `balbla` function will have finished running and returned before it the anonymous one is ever called.

If you want to do something with the response data, do it **inside the anonymous callback function**.

Answer (score 2):

[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is asynchronous, not synchronous. You need to use a callback so your logic needs to be done in two steps. Calling step and the processing step.

Comment: even if it was synchronous his code would not work since the `return` statement is not in the blabla function